I just have 1 monitor but xrandr show me 2 monitors, how to disable a not physical monitor
This is very strange, I use Ubuntu 22.04 and today I noted I supposly have 2 monitors, for that reason i am starting have issues, can´t configure settings as gnoma-contro-center appears in a Second (virtual) monitor, How can I disable that ???
This is the output of xrandr, note that i tried to disable second fake monitor but is not possible.

My real monitor is the WAYLAND1.

Look at the displays option under settings.

a not physical monitor ... phantom monitor .... search for that
